# prove that this is a cauchy sequence

Tags: real-analysis, exponential-function, cauchy-sequences, epsilon-delta

Prove that $\{x_n\}$  = $e^{-n}$ is a Cauchy sequence.

I tried to prove this by proving that,

For all $ϵ>0$, there is a positive $N$ s.t. for all $n>N$, 
 $|e^{-n}|< ϵ$
For all $ϵ>0$, there is a positive $N$ s.t. for all $m>N$, 
 $|e^{-m}|< ϵ$

I want some help with combining above two results to form
 For all $ϵ>0$, there is a positive $N$ s.t. for all $n,m>N$, 
 $|e^{-n} - e^{-m} |< ϵ$

Comment: Are you required to use a $\epsilon - \delta$ proof? If not, you should know that Convergent $\Leftrightarrow$ Cauchy.

Comment: yes I wanted to prove this using ϵ−δ proof.

Answer (score 3):

If you insist on wanting to show that your sequence is Cauchy without using convergence:

Suppose $m \geq n \geq N$. In that case

$$|e^{-m} - e^{-n}| = e^{-n} - e^{-m} = e^{-n} (1 - e^{n - m}) \leq e^{-n} \leq e^{-N}.$$

Now for $\varepsilon > 0$, you can pick $N$ such that $e^{-N} \leq \varepsilon$.

Answer (score 2):

It converges to $0$!
So it is in particular a Cauchy sequence (every convergent sequence is Cauchy).

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**: If $m \ge n$, then $ 0 < e^{-m} \le e^{-n}$, and so $0 \le e^{-n}-e^{-m} < e^{-n}$.

Similarly, if $n \ge m$, then $0 < e^{-n} \le e^{-m}$, and so $-e^{-m} < e^{-n}-e^{-m} \le 0$.